# Arrays as a hash's value: get the 2 arrays with most elements

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have a hash with arrays as values:

```
my_hash = { 
            "team1" => ["John", "Arthur", "David"], 
            "team2" => ["Eline", "Jessica"], 
            "team3" => ["Matt", "Bill", "Frank", "Bob"] 
          }
```

How can I retrieve the keys of the 2 arrays with the biggest number of elements in it ? 
Here, it should return:

```
"team1"  # has 3 elements
"team3"  # has 4 elements
```

I tried to use:

```
my_hash.select { |k, v| v.max }
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It is far from _exactly_. Do you need top two?

Comment: I need to be able to define how many of the top I ca retrieve. In my example I said 2, and if I can make it work with 2 I'll be able to make it work with n

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
my_hash.max_by(2) { |_, v| v.size }.map(&:first)
```

**Note**: The numeric argument of `Enumerable#max_by` was introduced in Ruby 2.2.0.

Comment: I am guessing down vote is because there is no explanation provided for answer.  One can say its self-explanatory - however, assuming OP is new to Ruby, explanation would be helpful.   I am looking up documentation to figure out what is parameter `2` to `max_by` mean.

Comment: Readers:didn't know [Enumerable#max_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) took an argument? That was new with v2.2 Same for `minmax`, `max` and the "min" equivalents of course. Re the downvote, you've been around the block enough to know you'll never get answer. When that happens to me it brings a wry smile to my face (unless it's deserved of course).

Comment: @CarySwoveland, mentioned the argument being new in the answer. Can you come up with a pre-2.2.0 elegant solution to link to?

Comment: I think downvoter didn't like that you used `_` as one of the block parameters, I don't like it either. `k` would be fine

Comment: @boulder_ruby, [it's a convention in Ruby](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#underscore-unused-vars) to name the arguments that you are not going to use `_`. In fact it is even lightly integrated in the language itself. You can't name more than one argument `k`, however, you can use `_` multiple times.

Comment: mmm....well.....ok, if you say so. Seems a little obfuscating to me until you know why you're doing that. Seems a little python-esque to me....what have you, to each his own. Nice style guide though, I'll study this later

Comment: @boulder_ruby, though it looks pythony, I think it originated from Haskel. Many languages have adopted it so far, so for me it's a recognized idiom.

Comment: Its a good one once you know what it means. I guess the ruby rub is that it could be confusing to some users that don't know what all the special keywords. The `_` looks like it might have special powers even though we know it doesn't

Comment: I didn't say it was new. Now that 2.3 is out, 2.2 is definitely *passe*. But no, I can't think of a nice pre-2.2 solution.  @boulder_ruby, use the underscore (a legit local variable) serves two purposes: it tells the reader, "I'm not using this variable in the block calculation" and it reduces the chances for a bug in that calculation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code can do it

`my_hash.map { |k, a| [k, a.size] }.to_h.sort_by {|_key, value| value}.to_h.keys.last(2)`

Comment: Sorting is inefficient when you only need the top two.